# Connection timed out when trying to make a simple Http GET request

Tags: java, eclipse, http, proxy, http-get

I'm trying to make a simple GET request:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=stuff
```

I've used the Apache Http Lybrary:

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class INRIX {

    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        INRIX inrix = new INRIX();


        try {
            inrix.peticionGet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inrix.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void close() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }

    private void peticionGet() throws Exception {

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com/search?q=stuff");

        // Request Headers
        getRequest.addHeader("custom-key", "stuff");
        getRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Googlebot");

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest)) {

            // Get HttpResponse Status
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Header headers = entity.getContentType();
            System.out.println(headers);

            if (entity != null) {
                // return it as a String
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println(result);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("ClientProtocolException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And HttpURLConnection:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class INRIXURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        INRIXURL inrix = new INRIXURL();

        inrix.peticionGet();
    }

    public void peticionGet() {

        String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=stuff";

        HttpURLConnection httpClient;
        try {
            httpClient = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            httpClient.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // add request header
            httpClient.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            int responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpClient.getInputStream()))) {

                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }

                // print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

In both cases I get timed out.

Error in the first case:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   www.google.com:443 [www.google.com/216.58.201.132] failed: Connection
>   timed out: connect    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>     at connCarPackage.INRIX.peticionGet(INRIX.java:53)  at
>   connCarPackage.INRIX.main(INRIX.java:26) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>     ... 11 more

For the second case:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown
>   Source)   at urlConnection.INRIXURL.peticionGet(INRIXURL.java:31)     at
>   urlConnection.INRIXURL.main(INRIXURL.java:14)

I think I might be related to the proxy configuration at my workplace, but I don't know how to check or fix it if that's the case or if I'm just not doing the request properly. I noticed that I can't ping sites or machines outside the company network but I don't know if it is related.

Also using https://reqbin.com/ the request works fine and I can browse without problems.

Answer (score 5):

As you said :

> I think I might be related to the proxy configuration at my workplace,  [...]

You should ask your **IT** how to use your companies proxy (or check your network settings, which might show you the proxy settings)

Also have a look here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: I just tried at home and it worked so it's probably that. I just wanted to be sure that the code I had was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while running Performance Test with 200 concurrent users for my java application and I was connected through evpn to my workplace network. I tried switching to a different network and it worked.

The issue occurred once the number of request reaches ~16K( this might be specific to my application), but switching to a different network and restarting my evpn worked for me.